# Proper Way to initialize a model class with data gathered from the system (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, model-view-controller, initialization

I need certain types of system information available to configure my app. I want to achieve this by having a model class which makes the information available. I know how to get the desired information but i am struggling to store this gathered information in the properties of my model class.

i want to be able to:

`let sysInfoModel = SysInfoModel()`

`let installedOsVersion = sysInfoModel.osVersion`

The model class should be instantiated from the vieController which needs this information to set up. 
I think my whole attempt is wrong to achieve such thing. What is the proper way to do so?

```
class SysInfoModel {

    // Properties
    let macModel: String?
    let osVersion: String?

    // Initialization
    init() {
        if let actualModel = getMacModel() { //ERROR: 'self' used in method call 'getMacModel' before all stored properties are initialized
            self.macModel = actualModel
        } else {
            macModel = "Hardware model not found"
        }

        if let actualOsVersion = getOsVersion() { // ERROR: 'self' used in method call 'getOsVersion' before all stored properties are initialized
            osVersion = actualOsVersion
        } else {
            osVersion = "OS Version not available"
        }
    }


    // Returns the hardware model identifier as a string
    func getMacModel()  -> String? {

        var modelIdentifier: String?

        let service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"))
        if let modelData = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, "model" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? Data {
            modelIdentifier = String(data: modelData, encoding: .utf8)
        }

        IOObjectRelease(service)
        return modelIdentifier
    }

    // Returns the OS Version as a String
    func getOsVersion() -> String? {

        let osVersion: OperatingSystemVersion = ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion
        let osVersionString = String("\(osVersion.majorVersion).\(osVersion.minorVersion).\(osVersion.patchVersion)")

        return osVersionString
    }
}
```

Update after matt's answer:

```
// Properties
var askSystem: AskTheSystem
let macModel: String?
let osVersion: String?

init() {

    askSystem = AskTheSystem()

    if let actualModel = askSystem.getMacModel() {
        self.macModel = actualModel
    } else {
        macModel = "Hardware model not found"
    }

    if let actualOsVersion = askSystem.getOsVersion() {
        osVersion = actualOsVersion
    } else {
        osVersion = "OS Version not available"
    }
}
```

I did, there is the possibility to put the functions `getMacModel()` & `getOsVersion()` in a separate class called  `AskTheSystem`. Instantiate it in the `SysInfoModel`.
It works but is this good practice ? i don't see the point in adding another class just for those functions ?  What is the proper way to do so ?

Comment: Proper is a judgment. Why is your approach wrong? Is it because of the compile errors? Then think about those instead.

Comment: Unrelated but why are the `String` properties optional as you are clearly assign a non-optional value in the `init` method? The code will compile also without the question marks. And why do you create a `String` from a `String` in `getOsVersion()`?

Comment: Unrelated but useful information... thank you, your right, they are not necessary, i remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with matt, *proper is a judgement*.

A reasonable solution are lazy instantiated properties, both values are retrieved **once** when the property is accessed the first time

```
class SysInfoModel {

    // Returns the hardware model identifier as a string
    lazy var macModel : String = {
        let service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"))
        defer{IOObjectRelease(service)}
        guard let modelData = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, "model" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? Data else {
            return "Hardware model not found"
        }
        return String(data: modelData, encoding: .utf8)!
    }()

    // Returns the OS Version as a String
    lazy var osVersion : String = {
        let osVersion = ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion
        return "\(osVersion.majorVersion).\(osVersion.minorVersion).\(osVersion.patchVersion)"
    }()

}
```

Comment: Thank you `@vadian`. this solved my problem in just the way i hoped there's a solution for. Thank you, I appreciate your efforts.